# Install Application At Client PC which uses MSSql Server as Backend

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I have one `WinForm` Application which using `MS-SQL server` As Database.

now off course Database i have created on my PC(**Developer's PC**) is not available on **Client PC** where i will install my Application.

Then what is the **best criteria** or **practice** to Add Database at **Client PC's** MS-SQL server.

So i can access it my Application.

Please Help....
Thanks.......

Comment: If your application uses MSSQL Express edition then embed SQL Server in your application. Please read this post - http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/how-to-embed-sql-server-express-in-an-application.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the actually size of the database, I would suggest you use SQL Conpact provider as you won't then need to worry about the whole setup process of installing SQL Server.

Good article to get started using [Sql Compact](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

First you need to ensure that MSSql server is installed in the Clients PC. Assuming you have that taken care of, you could add Custom actions during installations which would execute the script to install the Database on the Client machine.

The exact way to do that of course depends on how you are creating the Installer Program.

Comment: where could i find Scrip of Database i have created?.....so i can directly execute it on client PC? Thank you so much for answering

Comment: There are several ways, depending on your environment. In SQL Server Management Studio, there are options in the file menu that exports a certain database.